# Did the US miltary ever reverse-engineer Goa'uld or other alien energy weapons?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

The SG- teams often bring back weapons like Jaffa staves and zat-guns, did they ever take any apart so they could learn to make energy weapons of their own?

Comment: they work at it, then the azgard give them their tech, so why bother.

Comment: It seemed like SG1 ended up using the stun-mode capable Gou'old weapons quite regularly at one point.

Answer (score 9):

As Jack put it, Jaffa Staff weapons are weapons of terror. The US Military has no interest in terror. They already have superior weapons of war, they are made to kill your enemy. The p90 is more accurate at a farther range, and has proven better than Goa'uld weapons.

That said, all tech found is researched at the SGC and Area 51, as seen in multiple episodes. The US Air Force did reverse engineer the goa'uld Death Glider,  to create their first space worthy fighter, which quickly backfired due to Goa'uld anti reverse engineering counter measures. The staff weapons are uses for research in building better armor for the SG teams.

Comment: The US Military has no interest in terror. HA! Any decent military force has an interest in terror.

Comment: @Omegacron - There is a difference between terror and fear. Militaries do not want to terrorize their enemy, they want to be feared.

Comment: The recall device had nothing to do with reverse engineering but to enact revenge against a deserter or betrayer.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no. At first they lacked knowledge to do that - remember that everything Goa'uld is naquadah powered. Only after first Ancient Knowledge repository (**Ep. "The fifth race**") enough knowledge was gained to build working naquadah generator (but it still took years).

In the meantime the gunpowder weapons proved adequate to fight Goa'uld and Replicators. As another answer suggests - they were weapon of war, while Staffs and zat guns were weapons of terror. Also the gunpowder weapons were already available and people knew how to use it.
And then there was an enormous leap in tech base for Earth and Goa'uld weapons were deemed obsolete compared to Asgard/Ancient tech.

I did ask myself the same question: why not rework staff weapons into something better (that is: drop blast projector onto some sort of modern weapon stock), but it would require a lot of work, knowledge and of course power source. At the time every bit of naquadah was needed for research and power generation, later to power up fleet of ships, so I gather it was deemed uneconomical and with unreliable source of power for "ammunition" rather risky.

Also, there was a plasma (?) gun built completely using Earth tech (**Ep. "Bounty"**)... It was a bit bulky...

Comment: Technically not "gunpowder" weapons. The term "ballistic" weapons would be a good way to distinguish guns from the alien energy weapons.

Comment: Technically correct, but that includes all sort of projectile weapons not gunpowder based. The Rail guns are quite late introduction and out of scope for this question... I am, however, convincible to changing that to "explosive propellant" to cover missiles.... How about that compromise?

Comment: I only say ballistic, as none of the Goa'uld or Asgard weapons are ballistic, and all of the Tau'ri weapons are (excepting various explosive and melee weapons).

Comment: Sorry, but you're incorrect. Goa'uld used bombs, which were energy explosive devices dropped by Al'kesh class. Bombs are ballistic weapons...

Comment: "excepting various explosive and melee weapons"

Comment: I would agree with you on principle, but as it's somewhat artificial distinction, I'll take exception to that. Grenades (and Goa'uld equivalent) and aerial bombs are used extensively in warfare, in contrast to melee weapons (which are mostly of duelling and ritual use). Additionally Earth employs guided missiles, which most certainly **are not** ballistic. And last but not the least: at the ranges the engagements were fought over, the projectile trajectory is basically flat, so "ballistic" would be more of a concept description rather than actual issue... So I'm keeping my classification. ;)